# Different Images on Google Maps API StaticMap Than on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am getting different building shadows when calling https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.1150139,-88.2273797&zoom=17&size=600x400&maptype=satellite

vs what I get from visiting

https://www.google.com/maps/@40.1150139,-88.2273797,319m/data=!3m1!1e3

I assume these are taken at different times of the day. How can I get the same image I am getting from Google Maps by calling the API?

Comment: Please include the full url for first link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get satellite imagery for different timestamps via Google Maps Static Maps API at the moment.

The Google issue tracker contains a feature request to make it possible. You can have a look at the feature request:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35826354

Feel free to star it to add your vote and subscribe to notifications.